# How do I write a script that shows all aliases upon startup of terminal

Tags: bash, alias

I am a new user learning to use Linux.  I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with several aliases created, and saved in the ~/.bashrc directory.  I am trying to write a welcome script that also displays the current aliases upon start up.  The current code I have is as follows:

```
    #! /bin/bash
    echo -e "\nWelcome $USER"
    echo -e "Today's date is: \c"
    date
    echo -e "\vHave \vA \VGreat \vDay! \c"
    echo -e "\nCurrent aliases for reference are:"
    alias
```

Upon startup, or running the script on it's own, the welcome message runs but the actual alias command does not?

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you are expecting.

Comment: if you then run `alias` "by hand" do you see any output? in other words do you have any aliases?

Comment: I would prefer for the output to be:
welcome user
The date and time
have a nice day
current aliases for reference are:
"and a list of the aliases just as if the (alias) command was run by hand"
(alias update='./aptdupdate'  ...... ect)

If I run it by hand outside of the script and just in the terminal window I do indeed receive the aliases I have created along with those that are standard to the shell.

Comment: Just source this script! (prepent a dot an a space before you call it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

> (...) saved in the ~/.bashrc directory. (...)

Well, I must point that `.bashrc` is a file, not a directory, and is part of the [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

That said, the reason why running the `alias` command inside a script does not work as expected is that it is a [shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), and when invoking it from a script [will not behave as if running it from your shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not).

Hence, the quickest thing you can do is store your aliases in a different file, like `~/.bash_aliases` and ensure it will be loaded by adding this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    source ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

And then read that file directly from your script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "\nWelcome $USER"
echo -e "Today's date is: \c"
date
echo -e "\vHave \vA \VGreat \vDay! \c"
echo -e "\nCurrent aliases for reference are:"
cat ~/.bash_aliases
```